# How to set image size for Materialize Media Box when opened

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm just creating a quick webpage for viewing my art inspiration. I'm making all of the images use the Media Box feature of Materialize CSS so I can display them side by side, and click on an image to make it bigger. I have the images sized the way I want them when not clicked. But when clicked, the image opens up to max size. For most of my images, this isn't a problem. But for a few, max possible size is larger than the image size, which results in it being blurry. Is there any css that affects the images once opened?

My html code:

```
<img class="materialboxed img-size" data-caption="Map of Exandria" src="./Maps/Exandria.jpg"/>
```

My css code for the non-clicked view:

```
.img-size {
     max-height: 300px;
     margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this, I hope it answers your question.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="Picstudy.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Pictures</title>   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="pic"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/F3j7wHn/1.jpg" ></div>
        <div class="pic"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/2qfLZMh/2.jpg"></div>
        <div class="pic"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/DtpCdGF/3.jpg"></div>
        <div class="pic"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/VV09ZBq/4.jpg"></div>
        <div class="pic"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/g4Tj5nL/6.jpg"></div>
        <div class="pic"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/bQ619ct/7.jpg"></div>
        
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
.page{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
   
    
    
}

img{
    height:100px ;
    width: 300px;
    position: static;
    
}
img:hover{
    height:inherit;
    width: inherit;
}
```